Set background colour in Windows Terminal, with git bash ANSI escape OSC 11 doesn't work
How do I get git bash to set terminal background colour using OSC Ansi Escape sequences?
printf %b '\e]11;rgb:30/00/00\a'
It works when I do it from WSL bash and for some servers when I ssh to them from git bash I can also set the background color.
I tried different ways of doing it, printf, echo -n \e or \033 etc.
So in the link @Destroy666 provided i got the debug tap for terminal, turns out git bash doesn't send the ANSI escape sequence when it is OSC 11. Can this behaviour be changed?

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6634

@Destroy666 I don't think this is the same issue, I get coloured output, but OSC 11 (VT100 background) doesn't work.
